# implement Oauth1 Provider in java

Tags: java, oauth, spring-security, oauth-provider

I need to create my own oauth1 provider in java. Can any one help me how can i create oauth1 provider in java.
Currently i'm using this package for implement it but can't get more help about how can i use this.[using this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/oauth1/AuthorizedRequestToken.html)

I google this question but didn't get any helping material. If some one give a link or working example , i will appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

did you consider using [Spring's oAuth extension](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/)?